# LIghts flickering across multiple circuits

Tags: electrical

I've found multiple questions that are similar to mine, but not quite the same.

I have multiple LED lights that occasionally flicker (maybe a few times an hour, for about 15 seconds). Not like a "trying to turn on and then turning off" kind of flicker, like a very visible 10Hz-ish-I'm-going-to-have-a-seizure kind of flicker. This happens to multiple lights: bathrooms, hallways on different sides of the house, dining room, and entryway. All told it's three different circuits. When the flicker happens, they all flicker. They otherwise work perfectly fine.

I cannot seem to connect the flickering to anything consistent: sometimes the heater is running, sometimes it's not. Sometimes the fridge is running, sometimes it's not. I tried replacing the light switches on a whim, but that changed nothing. These are all just dumb switches, by the way-- no dimmers or anything.

I don't really know what to investigate, here. My appliances appear to work without issue. My outlets appear to work without issue. I don't notice any flickering in the LED trim lights I put into my pot lights; it's possible those are too high on the vaulting ceiling for me to really notice, but that seems like a dumb explanation for why they don't seem to be flickering when honestly at least half the house seems to be. If I want to go to a rave, I'd like to do so by my own free will.

**Update 1:** every single one of these bulbs are new, from Home Depot. I recently purchased this house and went on a color temperature matching spree (we've all been there, right?). I just noticed that one of the bulbs in question, in a bathroom, is dead. That seems relevant.

**Update 2:** Scratch the previous update, that bulb was just loose. Between all of the flickering lights, the brand is the same. The entryway and dining lights use [EcoSmart B11s](https://www.homedepot.com/p/EcoSmart-60-Watt-Equivalent-B11-Dimmable-ENERGY-STAR-Clear-Glass-Filament-Vintage-Edison-LED-Light-Bulb-Bright-White-3-Pack-FG-04075/311795728), and the hallways and bathrooms use [EcoSmart A19s](https://www.homedepot.com/p/EcoSmart-60-Watt-Equivalent-A19-Dimmable-Energy-Star-LED-Light-Bulb-Bright-White-4-Pack-B7A19A60WESD02/303574530?NCNI-5).

**Update 3:** I had the power company come out to put a monitor on the system, and they discovered that my junction box was completely full of gopher dirt. Much of the rails had corroded away. They replaced that, thinking it would solve the problem, but it hasn't. I'll call them again.

Comment: Sounds like your lights might be responding to "Time of Use" or "off-peak" signaling from the power company. see https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/183596/18078 for one example. is the timing (clock time) consistent?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_management

Comment: You said there are 3 different circuits all combined, but can you on any one circuit remove everything involved in that circuit besides the suspect bulbs and see if it happens? Next, what brand are they - are they all the same brand? Last, what about where you live, is there any ham radio or other "higher" power RF things going on? Is this daily (maybe a neighbor)

Comment: @Ecnerwal - yikes, our power supplier is switch mode power-supplying our 60Hz (or 50Hz) AC?!?! I'd go bonkers. They better pony up with some massive filter caps in those neighborhoods if thats the cause. Yuk.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, no, the timing isn't consistent. It happened three times in about three minutes just now. There's no pattern as far as I can tell.

Comment: @noybman, yes, one circuit currently has nothing on it other than the lights, and it still happens at the same time as the others. Regarding amateur radio, I don't _think_ so. I live out in the country, and at least the neighbors closest to me don't have any big antennas or anything. Regarding the brand, I'd have to check, but it's entirely possible they're the same. The majority certainly are (all the hallway lights).

Comment: Could be load-shedding / peaking signals (those would be somewhat random, where a non-adaptive "time of use" setup would be more consistent. Could be something else, too, I'm not sure what, though. If you happen to have an antique "normal" incandescent bulb it might be interesting to replace one or two LEDs with incandescents just to see what happens (*i.e.* do they also visibly flicker, or not)

Comment: What make/model are said LED bulbs?

Comment: Go down to your breaker panel and temporarily shut off all 240V circuits as well as all *multi-wire branch circuits* (which are supposed to be handle-tied).  Does anything weird happen with these lights?  Or, less weird?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I've updated the question with exact bulb details.

Comment: Still poking at the random that via occum's razor doesn't sound random! But, since you are looking at large appliances, read this and ponder??? https://www.doityourself.com/forum/electrical-ac-dc/622242-flickering-lights-oscilloscope-capture-included.html

Comment: Did you buy only new bulbs and use the old sockets? If so that could be the source of the problem. I experienced the same after replacing some halogen lamps with leds. Try to buy a new socket and see if the problem persists..

Comment: @Rubus some of the light fixtures were existing, yes, and I'm not sure I can swing replacing them all financially. Some of them are new though, and they're still flickering.

Comment: @kyrofa Maybe its a neutral break. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vb_3cEw3uxA) Measure the voltage of each of your circuits and check if it is according to the specifications of your country. Neutral breaks can cause different voltages in the system. Note that the term three phase system applies also to the constellation where you have one out of three phase plus neutral to power circuits like in Germany / Switzerland..If neutral break occurs at the inlet get ready for some strange phenomena

Comment: Use a digital multimeter to measure voltage because voltage drops or increases can be small but could theoretically cause flickering..The voltage should not be off more than 5V..But maybe an electrician could provide better information

Comment: I have seen this, before. The problem was transients coming in on the power line. The dimmer compatible LED bulbs responded to it much more then the non dimmer compatible bulbs. They would go out for a few cycles then come back on. Just long enough to be annoying. I had one start doing this after being fine for years. I had just replaced a tungsten lamp with a LED version, put a tungston in and the problem went away.

Comment: I had an issue similar to this, albeit my LEDs were on dimmers. But it's actually very important that the switch itself is LED compatible. And beyond that, even if the switch is LED compatible, some switches aren't compatible with all brands.

Once I swapped out the switches with proper LED ones, it was solved for me.

Comment: Wow, you've been struggling with this for a year?? Thanks for coming back with an update to let us know what's going on.

Comment: Almost three now, actually. I'm almost certain this is coming from the utility, but just haven't narrowed it down completely yet, i.e. gotten them to own it. I'll keep this up to date as the journey continues.

Answer (score 1):

Try monitoring the voltage (nominally 120V) on both bus bars  If one goes high while the other goes low the neutral connection between DB neutral bar and utility transformer is failing.  Most LED lights seem to have a hard drop-out voltage so (on a positive note!) LED's are good indicators of incipient failure.  Get the utility to look at it ASAP.  a complete neutral failure can result in over-V reaching almost 240V to some 120V loads under certain conditions. We lost a refrigerator and several 24V control transformers (boiler controls, hot tub) in one such incident!